# Generate HTML Pages with JasperReports on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jasper-reports

I currently have a class, Reporter.java, which uses JasperReports to generate an HTML report. I have a simple Test.java that calls Reporter.report() and the HTML file is properly generated at a specified file location (I currently have it set as a C:/ path that points into my Tomcat project). Now, I run a Tomcat server with an HTML page that calls generateStatus.jsp which calls Reporter.report() and an exception is thrown.

```
Jun 30, 2011 3:02:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/OATS] threw exception [javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperCompileManager] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager
  at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
  at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
  at com.home.oats.Reporter.report(Reporter.java:22)
  at org.apache.jsp.generateStatus_jsp._jspService(generateStatus_jsp.java:58)
  at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
  at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
  at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
  at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The line it errors at is

```
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasper.getString(Constants.JRXML));
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the Jasper Jar file in the `WEB-INF/lib` dir of your web-app.

Comment: I had it included in my project, but not WEB-INF/lib. I tried putting a copy of it into that folder but the exception persists.

Comment: In fact, I revisited this...and yes including all the dependencies in WEB-INF/lib fixes the problem. 
I do bump into the problem where a generated page is unable to be accessed unless I refresh my Eclipse project since the newly generated files aren't synced with the project.

Answer (score 0):

This was a good example to follow:

http://codebackup.wordpress.com/2008/02/29/howto-jasperreports-framework-deployment-to-tomcat/

But I am still looking into generating a "dump" of reports in a directory rather than displaying a report on a single HTML page.